# Testing magento core functions

Tags: magento-1.9, testing, phpunit

I been trying to find something to setup tests for my website, for functions like login, add to cart, add to wish list and so. And I tried finding something reliable but I been reading that it cant be tested with PHPUnit,now i might seen something thats not true, but i am a beginner with frameworks like this and not sure what to think, is there something i can use to set up the test i need, and if so please leave some links to it and to any sort of documents or guides?

Comment: Seems you want to do frontend tests on your website and not unit-testing?! Go ahead and look for frontend tests.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/magento/taf and https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting

which are frameworks which already implement a lot of tests. But only work on demo data(?) and default theme afaik

Answer (score 0):

I played this year a bit with DalekJS and started to refactor https://github.com/luemic/magento-dalekjs into https://github.com/Flyingmana/magento-dalekjs for a more modular usage, maybe this is a good start for you.

Benefit of DalekJS is, you can also do Browser based testing with chrome, internet explorer and so on. (firefox is a bit buggy, as they often change internal APIs)

Answer (score 0):

Found this question and maybe someone is still interested in unit testing on Magento 1. As Fabian already mentioned [TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting](https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting) is a framework for unit and integration tests. Especially the unit testing part was added later in order to be able run real unit tests on Magento 1. [Here](https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting/wiki) is some documentation with examples for unit testing with this framework in Magento 1: https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_MagentoUnitTesting/wiki